# how to retrieve the openshift container pod name using python?

Tags: python, kubernetes, openshift, redhat

I have my python applications running in redhat open shift container, for logging purpose i want to print/get the pod name programatically in python, i have no idea how to do it can someone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openshift: Get current pod name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166991/openshift-get-current-pod-name)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use the [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/), pass the information you need as environment variables and read the variable from your process

Example:

```
env:
- name: MY_NODE_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: spec.nodeName
- name: MY_POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
- name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

Available fields: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/

Answer (score 0):

The hostname in the container will be the Pod name. You can find using `os.uname` or `os.environ` in Python:

```
import os

print(os.uname()[1])
print(os.environ['HOSTNAME'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#module-socket) and its [gethostname()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname) functionality. This will get the hostname and in turn the openshift/kubernetes pod name where the Python interpreter is running:

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```